# How do I allow users to share links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am new to ruby on rails and web development in general, just learning how to make stuff from whatever tutorials I can get. I was wondering how I can allow users to share links. I can have them upload files using paperclip but I want to make a feature that allows users to share links like they would on twitter or facebook, and after that I want to show a preview of the link, if its link to a youtube video I want to be able to view it on the site without having to go to youtube. Are there any gems for this, and how can I get this done?

Answer (score 3):

Gems are just basic components for to build your own amazing application. So you can't find what exactly what you need, often you need to do it yourself.

For example, there is a gem called [LinkThumbnailer](https://github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer). This gives you many opportunities, including working with youtube videos:

```
object = LinkThumbnailer.generate('http://stackoverflow.com')
 => #<LinkThumbnailer::Models::Website:...>

object.title
 => "Stack Overflow"

object.favicon
 => "//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=038622610830"

object.description
 => "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers"
```